# jqgrid subgrid hide +- symbol is not showing up

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

[image]jqgrid subgrid hide +- symbol is not showing up. on click the row expands but the symbol doesn't appear. I have included the following files

jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js
jquery.jqGrid.min.js

jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css
ui.jqgrid.css

Please help

In the image you can see the + & - symbols are not appearing even though the row gets expand

Comment: Do you have the JqueryUI themes installed? as the images might not be there

Comment: Qpirate, Please let me know how to install it. Means, is there any procedure/process steps to follow

Comment: use this to create your theme http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ and then just add a reference to the style sheet in your masterpage, you should then be able to use the icon classes.

Comment: your question don't include any code. Without the code one can only guess, which is not effective. If you write about CSS and JavaScript files you should include the exact list in the same order in which you use there.